Vba code showing error 75 path/file access error. For this line of code Open startFile For Output As #startFileNum
    Sub FetchAndExportUserData()
        Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim sourceRow As Long
        Dim userID As String
        Dim startDate As String
        Dim endDate As String
        Dim startFile As String
        Dim endFile As String
        
        ' Specify the path for the output files
        startFile = "C:\Output_StartDate.txt"
        endFile = "C:\Output_EndDate.txt"
        
        ' Open or create the output files
        Dim startFileNum As Integer
        Dim endFileNum As Integer
        startFileNum = FreeFile()
        endFileNum = FreeFile()
        Open startFile For Output As #startFileNum
        Open endFile For Output As #endFileNum
        
    End Sub

I got

Error 75
path/file access error

at this line
        Open startFile For Output As #startFileNum
Help to find solution

The usual possible reasons: Drive C is not available at all. The root folder of drive C: is write protected. The file exists and you have no right to overwrite it. The file exists and is temporarily write protected because it's already open, either by another application or maybe because your macro was executed a 2nd time and you haven't closed the file the first time.
